# ubuntu: root password

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, passwords, sudo

Well, I don't know exactly how it happened. But, thing is if I issue a command which I need root priviliges an error message comes that says `<user> does not have an entry in sudoers file`

**I used to work in terminal after issuing *sudo bash***

Sometime back I installed postgresql using apt-get. It does not start as it takes some temporary (or any other, I'm not sure) as /var/run which postgres user did not have permissions. Well, simply I could have changed that dir to /tmp (which ultimately I did), but before that I played with the things. One of them (I don't remember why) was `I tried to add a <user> to postgres group.`

Well, that day things went well, but next day (I think after a restart) `that <user> could not execute commands with sudo`.

Now, I need to install dblink for postgres which I believe needs sudo permissions. `Is there anyway to restore sudo permissions to that <user>`

Or atleast, is there anyway to install dblink for postgresql without needing sudo thing??

Comment: [Ask Ubuntu!](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: Please note that although @Mehrdad is correct, and AskUbuntu is a good site. Please do not cross-post there.

Answer (score 1):

Start your unbuntu in maintenance mode. You'll be given root shell.

Issue a `visudo` command to edit the sudoers files.

Then verify you have

```
user     ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

line. Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought ESC would help in starting ubuntu in maintenance mode. But ESC, DEL, F2 I tried all but did not work. How should I do it.

Comment: This is an option in the GRUB. At startup you usually choose your system or the fallback one. You can use `e` to edit the line. Add single at the end validate and then `b` to boot. Look it up on google, there is plenty of tutorial for this.